# output from McPat to another directory not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gem5

I am following the tutorial here https://github.com/Hardik44/Gem5toMcPat_parser

when I run this command

```
./mcpat -infile mcpat-out.xml -print_level 5 -opt_for_clk 1 > mcpatoutput
```

it works fine but when I go to the mcpatoutput directory, no file in it.

what might be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

`./mcpat ... > mcpatoutput` will write the command output to the `mcpatoutput` file in the current directory. You will find the output file in the same directory as the `.mcpat` executable.